# Use python to format/insert comma into data lines

Tags: python, sql

I have a regularly appended CSV file with two types of similar data.  I can't control how the data come into the CSV - but I want to execute a python script that will format the CSV so that I can ingest it into a database.  Here is what I want to do:

Incoming raw data look like this:

```
record, date & time, sensor, height, status

record, date & time, sensor, height, weight, status
```

The idea would be to just take these data iteratively add a comma after height if no weight or something like that.  Essentially mimic a blank field so that the data would essentially look like this:

```
record, date & time, sensor, height, **weight,**status (updated after python script if/then)

record, date & time, sensor, height, weight, status
```

Hopefully that makes sense - Basically adding a field and I would run the script every time the file is updated.

Comment: Do You care about csv escaping and quotes?

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
import os
with open('yourfile.csv') as f_in, open('yourfile.csv.temp') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 5:
            row.insert(4, '')
        writer.writerow(row)
os.rename('yourfile.csv.temp', 'yourfile.csv')
```